# Non bootable disk error with bootable USB drive

Tags: boot, live-usb

I have used UNetbootin to make a 4GB USB stick into a bootable media but keep running up against the same problem.

I removed the partitions and formatted the USB drive as MBR and added a single FAT32 partition. Then I cleared the /tmp/ directory and had UNetbootin make an Ubuntu (AMD64) bootable disk on the USB device. The bootable flag is set, the files etc look correct but on more than one device I get the error message that this is not a bootable device.

What has gone wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: I was typing the answer to put you on the right track to booting from USB, but am concerned about being voted down for helping (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161735/grant-ftp-access-to-specific-directory/161740?noredirect=1#comment264801_161740).

Comment: Honestly, I did not mean to make you feel bad on that other question. Go for it, this is a particularly safe question to attack as it is purely academic at this stage but I would like to figure out what went wrong for next time.

Comment: Consider the possibility of an incomplete iso download, was your internet not connected at the time of download? If you are sure of the iso and you have an alternative usb, use it for bootable! You also didn't need to format and create partitions! With the command ```dd if=/path/to/file/iso of=/dev/sdx```, it will burn the entire file in /dev/sdx of your disk! 
Warning: Make sure you select your USB disk! Check your disk and partitions with the ```lsblk``` command